# How to use localhost instead of localhost IP in spring?

Tags: java, spring

In application-dev.properties I have this 
this line

```
spring.host.server=10.52.129.2
```

and instead of that,
I want to use something like :

```
spring.host.server=http://localhost : 4200
```

I tried even this

```
spring.host.server=localhost:4200
```

is there any possible to use something diff

> 

Comment: Did you simply try `spring.host.server=localhost` ?

Comment: Where is the port in `spring.host.server=10.62.129.2` ?

Comment: No, I didn't try that but I will try it now and let you know

Comment: @ScaryWombat what do you mean?
Do you mean the file?
The file is application-dev.properties
and is the ip of the server

Comment: Your property just represents a host, by ip or by name, there is no port or protocol to add to that .

Comment: What I meaning is that you are starting with a value without a port number and then blaming the use of `localhost` as the reason that you suddenly can add a `colon` and a `port` on to it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat ok I got I, but is there any workaround, to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring.host.server` is not documented in Spring Boot(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).
It is a custom property introduced by your application.

> but the ":" is misunderstood and the link is wrong,

It means that your application doesn't parse the property value to detect if it contains a `:` character and then split it as two things : the host and the port.    It uses very probably the property value such as for the host value and use a default port.  So you have no way to value the port actually.

To solve it, either change the code that use the property to split it `(String.split(":"))` into two parts if it contains a `:` character or introduce a second property such as :

```
spring.server.host=localhost
spring.server.port=4200
```

Comment: You should post your code, it should help to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set port, simply add in properties file: server.port=4200